# Maybe constructing data from Maybes

Tags: haskell

I have a type

```
data Foo = Foo { bar :: Bar, baz :: Baz }
```

and I am trying to parse a file to construct a `Foo`. I have functions to try parsing the `Bar` and `Baz` members

```
parseBar :: String -> Maybe Bar
parseBar line = ...

parseBaz :: String -> Maybe Baz
parseBaz line = ...
```

that may fail, and a function that maybe constructs the `Foo` from the results

```
parseFoo :: String -> Maybe Foo
parseFoo line = let bar = parseBar line
                    baz = parseBaz line
                in parseFoo' bar baz

parseFoo' :: Maybe Bar -> Maybe Baz -> Maybe Foo
parseFoo' (Just bar) (Just baz) = Just Foo { bar=bar baz=baz }
parseFoo' _ _ = Nothing
```

This gets the job done, but defining the extra function just to do the pattern matching seems clumsy. Is there a cleaner way to either "unbox" the `Maybe Bar` and `Maybe Baz` or return `Nothing`? Am I going about this all wrong? (I'm still working my way up to monads. I just really wanted to actually write something now that I've made it to Hello, World nine chapters in.)

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code. `Applicative`, which you'll meet on the way towards monads, is the natural way of making it feel less clumsy (in particular, `parseFoo' = liftA2 Foo`).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Luckily you don't need the full power of monads for this. [Applicative functors](http://learnyouahaskell.com/functors-applicative-functors-and-monoids#applicative-functors) are all you need:

```
parseFoo line = Foo <$> parseBar line <*> parseBaz line
```

Answer (score 8):

This is what the `Monad` instance of `Maybe` is all about. You can thus calculate your `Maybe Foo` with:

```
parseFoo :: String -> Maybe Foo
parseFoo line = do
    bar <- parseBar line
    baz <- parseBaz line
    parseFoo' bar baz
```

Here `bar` and `baz` are not `Maybe Bar` and `Maybe Baz` objects, but `Bar` and `Baz` objects. You thus can define a `parseFoo` with:

```
parseFoo' :: Bar -> Baz -> Maybe Foo
parseFoo' bar baz = Just Foo { bar=bar baz=baz }
```

Here from the moment a computation returns a `Nothing`, it means that the result is a `Nothing`, so only if the `parseBar line` returns a `Just …`, and the `parseBaz` returns a `Just …`, it will thus return the result of `parseFoo bar baz`.

This is because the `Monad` instance of `Maybe` is implemented as:

```
instance Monad Maybe where
    return = Just
    Nothing >>= _ = Nothing
    Just x >>= f = f x
```

A [`do` block is syntactical sugar](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#dx8-47001), so the above `do` block is converted to:

```
parseFoo line = parseBar line >>= \bar -> (parseBaz line >>= \baz -> parseFoo bar baz)
```

If `parseFoo` always returns `Just` in case it retrieves two `Just`s, we can implement this as:

```
parseFoo' :: Bar -> Baz -> Foo
parseFoo' bar baz = Foo { bar=bar baz=baz }
```

In that case we can make ues of [**`(<$>) :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-60--36--62-) and [**`(<*>) :: Applicative f => f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-60--42--62-) to process the data:

```
parseFoo :: String -> Maybe Foo
parseFoo line = parseFoo' <$> parseBar line <*> parseBaz line
```

In this specific case, `parseFoo` is however semantically the same as `Foo`, so we do not need a `parseFoo`, and can work with:

```
parseFoo :: String -> Maybe Foo
parseFoo line = Foo <$> parseBar line <*> parseBaz line
```

Answer (score 3):

Before `Applicative`s, you still can do

```
parseFoo :: String -> Maybe Foo
parseFoo line = 
  case (parseBar line, parseBaz line) of
    (Just bar, Just baz) -> Just Foo { bar=bar baz=baz }
    _ -> Nothing
```

and avoid defining the `parseFoo'` function.